# Microsoft .NET Updates - KB3097996 and KB3098781 - Error 406 Error on .axd files

Tags: asp.net, .net-framework-version

stackoverflower's

Please note that the following updates KB3097996 and KB3098781 broke our company eCommerce Web site on all browsers Firefox (Could not add items to cart any longer), Chrome (could add to cart, but would not update item count on header) and Internet explorer (Nothing broke, but were getting 406 errors in the F12 Developer Tools).  All AJAX Code for ASP.NET

```
After the applying the updates we started receiving NetworkError: 406 Not 
Acceptable Error(s) on .axd files.   

TypeError: Sys.Webforms is undefined
Sys.WebForms.PageRequesManager._initialize('ScripManager1, 'Main_Form', tpn...

TypeError: Sys.Webforms is undefined var pgRegMgr = Syst.Webforms.PageRequesManager.getInstance()
```

I wanted to know if anybody else is having these issues and if there is a fix.  We simply rolled back the updates and I have let TechNet know.

Answer (score 0):

We have been experiencing intermittent errors since these updates were installed one of our internal servers that hosts WCF services in IIS. The services are compiled against .Net framework 4.5.1

The Application event log on the server shows

```
Faulting application name: w3wp.exe, version: 7.5.7601.17514, time stamp: 0x4ce7a5f8
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.34209,
time stamp: 0x5348961e
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x0000dfa7
Faulting process id: 0x10e8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d13c4f187f996e
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 7c01148e-a842-11e5-a7b4-005056880172
```

When this happens any in-progress calls to the web services fail.

I don't know of any fix for this, other than to uninstall the updates. I have read that .Net 4.6 doesn't have this issue, so if you are able to recompile your app against the newer framework you might get positive results.

We plan to use .net 4.6 for our web services in our next release, but for now we have uninstalled the updates. The security flaw really isn't an issue for the affected machine so we can live without the updates for the time being.